# Limitar renderização de imagens

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Estou usando o plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/ para relacionar imagens a categorias, e estou printando icones ao lado do titulo do post assim(código abaixo) mas ele trás todas categorias relacionada e eu queria **limitar para apenas uma** alguém pode me ajudar?:

```
<?php
        print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-list-the-terms', '', array(
            'attr'       => array(
            'alt'   => '',
            'class' => 'img-responsive',
            'src'   => '',
            'title' => '',
         ),
        'before'       => '<div class="">',
        'after'        => '</div>',
        'before_image' => '',
        'after_image'  => '',
        'image_size'   => 'detail',
        'post_id'      => get_the_ID()
) );


                ?>
```

Comment: troque sua primeira linha após `<?php` por `print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '' );`

Comment: Ele limita em algumas e em outras páginas da erro =/

Comment: Nas páginas de categoria funcionam mas quando vou para Home ele não funciona, apenas com o código antigo

Comment: Editei a resposta, tente novamente

Comment: O problema persiste =/

Comment: O erro aqui persiste pois o Tema usado (Odin) não suporta esse tipo de query (esse é o erro printado aqui na home).

Comment: Poderia editar a pergunta com o erro que está dando?

Comment: Notice: term_taxonomy_id is not a property of the current queried object. This usually happens when the taxonomy-images-queried-term-image-id filter is used in an unsupported template file. This filter has been designed to work in taxonomy archives which are traditionally served by one of the following template files: category.php, tag.php or taxonomy.php. Learn more about template hierarchy.

Comment: Copiei o erro acima

Answer (score 0):

Sei que já foi solucionado, mas só para não deixar sem resposta caso outra pessoa também tenha o mesmo problema, a solução é simples.

Na linha 2 do seu código, você vai substituir os termos:

```
print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-list-the-terms',
```

Por:

```
print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image'
```

No caso a única diferença é os argumentos `images-list-the-terms` e `images-queried-term-image`.

@edit - Para ficar mais fácil troque o código inteiro.

```
print apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '', array(
'attr'       => array(
    'alt'   => '',
    'class' => 'img-responsive',
    'src'   => '',
    'title' => '',
    ),
'before'     => '<div class="">',
'after'      => '</div>',
'image_size' => 'detail',
'post_id'      => get_the_ID()
 );
```

Comment: Tem ideia de como consigo fazer uma imagem aparecer do lado da outra? pois esse "before" e "after" renderizam assim:

<div><a href=""> {TODAS IMAGENS AQUI } </a> </div>